# In Azure Data bricks I want to get start dates of every week with week numbers from datetime column

Tags: sql, azure, databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

This is a sample Data Frame

```
Date    Items_Sold
12/29/2019  10
12/30/2019  20
12/31/2019  30
1/1/2020    40
1/2/2020    50
1/3/2020    60
1/4/2020    35
1/5/2020    56
1/6/2020    34
1/7/2020    564
1/8/2020    6
1/9/2020    45
1/10/2020   56
1/11/2020   45
1/12/2020   37
1/13/2020   36
1/14/2020   479
1/15/2020   47
1/16/2020   47
1/17/2020   578
1/18/2020   478
1/19/2020   3578
1/20/2020   67
1/21/2020   578
1/22/2020   478
1/23/2020   4567
1/24/2020   7889
1/25/2020   8999
1/26/2020   99
1/27/2020   66
1/28/2020   678
1/29/2020   889
1/30/2020   990
1/31/2020   58585
2/1/2020    585
2/2/2020    555
2/3/2020    56
2/4/2020    66
2/5/2020    66
2/6/2020    6634
2/7/2020    588
2/8/2020    2588
2/9/2020    255
```

I am running this query

```
%sql
use my_items_table;

select weekofyear(Date), count(items_sold) as Sum
from my_items_table
where year(Date)=2020
group by weekofyear(Date)
order by weekofyear(Date)
```

I am getting this output. (IMP: I have added random values in Sum)
Week     Sum
1    |   300091
2    |  312756
3    |   309363
4    |   307312
5    |   310985
6    |   296889
7    |   315611

But I want in which with week number one column should hold a start date of each week. Like this

```
Start_Date  Week    Sum
12/29/2019  1   300091
1/5/2020    2   312756
1/12/2020   3   309363
1/19/2020   4   307312
1/26/2020   5   310985
2/2/2020    6   296889
2/9/2020    7   315611
```

I am running the query on Azure Data Bricks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data for all days, then just use `min()`:

```
select min(date), weekofyear(Date), count(items_sold) as Sum
from my_items_table
where year(Date) = 2020
group by weekofyear(Date)
order by weekofyear(Date);
```

Note:  The `year()` is the calendar year starting on Jan 1.  You are not going to get dates from other years using this query.  If that is an issue, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question asking how to get the first day for the first week of the year.